# MongoDB Remove()

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following collection I am pulling from my `MongoDB` Atlas database:

```
[
  {
    _id: "foo",
    comment: 'Awesome baba',
    author: "Me"
  },
  {
    _id: "bar",
    comment: 'Awesome mama',
    author: "You"
  }
]
```

**When I use the remove({_id: "foo"}) method, the document is being successfully removed from the collection. However, when I use the remove({author: "You"}) method, the document is not being removed.**

What is really going on

Comment: Do you have a code snippet that demonstrates this behavior?

Comment: Oh what a noob I am. Discovered where I was going wrong, I was using the remove() method in a javascript instance and not in the mongodb instance.